# jQuery fileupload with drag&drop submits empty file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using jQuery fileupload plugin, which works quite well when uploading files by clicking the file input and choosing via the browser's dialog.

However when using drag & drop, it seems to submit an empty file input

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryCA4VuYwsPr7h4ItR
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

although the data object inside the fileupload's add callback does have a file right before calling data.submit()

```
files: Array[1]
  0: File
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Mar 18 2014 13:29:07 GMT+0100 (CET)
    name: "17_1395143728_0.png"
    size: 13542
    tempID: 1
    type: "image/png"
    webkitRelativePath: ""
    __proto__: File
  length: 1
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Edit: the code:

```
$(document).bind('drop.fileUpload', function (e) {
    if(jQuery(e.target).attr('id') !== 'dropZone'){
        return;
    }

    var fileInput = jQuery('#attachment');
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

    if (fileInput.length && files.length) {
        jQuery('#dropZone').hide();
        fileInput.fileupload('add', {files: files});

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

jQuery('.js_toggleFileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: true,
    forceIframeTransport: true,
    progressInterval: 50,
    url: '/xhr',
    add: function (e, data) {

        console.debug(data); // this is where the data object has files

        var jqXHR = data.submit().done(function (e, data) { // this is where an empty file input is submitted
            //stuff happens here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add your javascript code, please.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! The problem is using iframeTransport and drag & drop at the same time, which can't work since the iframeTransport option posts the file input to an iframe. In the case of drag & drop, the file input has an empty value.

I've turned off the forceIframeTransport option and now it works.